# Why did the byte before TXTTAB have to be zero in MS-BASIC?

Tags: microsoft-basic

As mentioned in [this answer about how the C64 stores BASIC program text](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14059/7208), MS-BASIC uses a pointer called `TXTTAB` that points to the start of the program text, which is typically at address 1 in a page. For example, on the Commodore 64 it's at address $0801:

```
PRINT PEEK(44), PEEK(43)
 8         1
```

As 8-Bit Show and Tell points out at [20:29 in this video](https://youtu.be/qWZyv1pomy4?t=1229) (which is demonstrating a technique developed decades ago), when moving the BASIC program text start area, you need to ensure that the byte just *before* your new `TXTTAB` start point is set to 0 for BASIC to function properly:

> POKE 1024 [the byte before the new `TXTPTR`], yeah, that's the start of BASIC memory, just putting a zero there, which is necessary; if you don't do that you'll get syntax error when you try to do anything in BASIC, even if you try and LIST.

This is not entirely correct; in VICE I tried `POKE 2048,1` and `LIST` still worked, but other commands, such as `NEW`, `RUN` and `GOTO 10` (after I'd entered a line 10) did produce `?SYNTAX ERROR`.

The Apple II+ (emulated with AppleWin) running Applesoft BASIC has similar issues; `POKE 2048,1` produces `?SYNTAX ERROR` when I type `NEW` (though it does clear the program) and with the program `10 PRINT "HELLO"` in memory, typing `RUN` produces `?SYNTAX ERROR in 65044`.

The same issues also arise on an MSX2 machine (Sony HB-F1XD emulated with OpenMSX): `POKE 32768,1` produces syntax errors for `NEW` and `RUN` with a program similar to the above.

Why is that location required to be zero?

Comment: Is this a duplicate or does the same answer apply? https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17475/basic-assembler-startup-code-c64

Comment: Is your emulator able to set a watchpoint on that address, so that it drops to the debugger when it is read or written?  That would help identify the code that accesses it, and then you could try to figure out what it does.

Comment: @Justme No, that's pretty much entirely unrelated. That guy's just got the start point for BASIC program text incorrect (he's using `[TXTTAB]-1` rather than `[TXTTAB]`). He could make it work fine after loading by setting the value in `TXTTAB` to $0800 and putting 0 in $07FF. Or recreate the problem above by putting 1 in $07FF. I am not shifting my program to the wrong location; I am simply changing a location just _outside_ my program, a location one that doesn't have any apparent use.

Comment: @cjs There is a comment that should be an answer for you : "on the first location a 0 is needed because the RUN command starts with the BASIC text pointer pointing to the last read character. This 0 byte provides an end-of-line condition, which let the interpreter search for the next line (an implicit GOTO 0) and advance to $801 as the first line to interpret" which is confirmed by another comment about disassebly of RUN.

Comment: @Justme Well, it turns out this is a duplicate question, or almost one, just not a duplicate of the question you were looking at. [Why does Applesoft get confused by a nonzero value at $0800?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20179/7208) doesn't mention that this is not an Applesoft-specific problem, but has an answer explaining what's going on with the `RUN` command, though not the `NEW` command. It didn't come up in my search because the answer misspells `TXTTAB` as `TEXTTAB`. (It is spelt correctly in comments on that answer; apparently search doesn't look at comments.)

Comment: (BTW, I'm leaving the question open in the hope that someone will explain what's up with `NEW`, and what other commands would also be affected by this design decision.)

Comment: If this is about  the details of New, then better  close this and do a _dedicated_ follow up to  [Why does Applesoft get confused by a nonzero value at $0800?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/why-does-applesoft-get-confused-by-a-nonzero-value-at-0800) focused on that item Otherwise it's just confusing future readers.

Comment: @Raffzahn Please read the previous comments. That post has already been linked by me with further explanation.

Comment: @Raffzahn I did read your original comment. Changing it with a drastic edit after I've responded and then scolding me for not knowing you were going to edit it is not very nice. I don't need the aggro, so let's not continue this discussion.

Comment: @cjs Mind to read as well? Thinking of it, since you seam to assume by default that others do not read comments (like shown by yourself) this makes a great example why redefinition in comments is not a good idea. If you still want to  know the fine details of NEW, closing and doing a focused question would be the way to go.

Comment: @cjs Which original comment? 4 years on RC.SE and it's still `NEW` to you that issuing a close by dupe does create an automated entry? Come on...  I think it's a good idea to turn such default entries into something more useful, do you? Also, the only 'aggro' here is added by you by replying within seconds in defensive manner.What about using that time to think rather before writing (did again, didn't you) and see how to improve your questions instead of trying to force it down?